# Why does the time it takes to start a Docker container vary that much?

Tags: docker

I have discovered that starting a Docker container varies a lot in time. E.g., I have started a RabbitMQ container using the official image on Docker for Mac 17.06, and the very same `docker run …` call took from 0.9s to 2.5s, with no specific pattern occuring.

And it is not only RabbitMQ, it happens with other containers as well: The time to run them varies a lot.

Why is that? Is there something I can do about it, to make startup times more deterministic? On other words: Is there something I might do wrong, what causes this strange behavior?

Comment: Are you running more containers on the same machine? Also have tried giving your container a fixed cpu using `--cpu 2.0` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: When I tried it, it was the only container running. But I'm going to try setting a fixed cpu.

Comment: PS: Which parameter do you mean? There is no `--cpu` flag AFAICS (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources).

Comment: Typo it should have been `--cpus`

Comment: Ah okay, thanks 